# How do I inform PyCharm of the location of custom modules?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an application at work that is set up with the following structure.

```
/project_root
    /applications
        /app1
            __init__.py
        /app2
            __init__.py
        ...
        /appN
    /pkg
        /database
            __init__.py
        /toolbox
            __init__.py
        ...
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
    main_framework.py
```

I'm investigating using PyCharm (community edition), instead of Eclipse's PyDev tool. In `__init__.py` in `app1` I have an import statement that looks like this:

```
import pkg.database
```

PyCharm complains about the import with a `no module named pkg` message.

[image: PyCharm Error]
(click for larger image)

Due to how the framework is built, though, the system runs just fine. Each of the `appN`s know about the `pkg` directory. How do I inform PyCharm that I have custom built modules in the `pkg` directory so that these warnings stop?

I am testing PyCharm 4.0.3 Community Edition.

A couple things I've tried, thanks for comments below, that haven't helped:

- In the Project Structure dialog, project_root was listed as the only directory under "Content Root" on the right hand side of the dialog. I've added the `pkg` directory so that it is listed as well. This had no effect.
- In the initial version of the question, I missed the `__init__.py` in `pkg` when displaying the structure. This file does exist.

Comment: Have you made `project_root` the source root for your project?

Comment: Try to use `project_root.pkg.database` even though I think it will not work. Second option, try to make also `pkg` a source root, mark it as `Source`. If this works, then tell me, and I will post this as an answer. I think the second should work.

Comment: The second option did not work (I set it as `Source` and then restarted PyCharm). I'll consider the first option if nothing else presents itself simply because I don't want to modify all the `appN` scripts if I don't need to.

Comment: @Matthias It could be...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution to this was a two step process:

1. Add the `pkg` directory as a source root. Do this by selecting `File` -> `Settings` -> `Project` -> (select the project) -> `Project Structure` then select the `pkg` directory and add by clicking the `Sources` button. Click Ok.
2. Then select `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` -> `Invalidate and Restart`

Wait for PyCharm to restart and rebuild it's cache / scan the indexes. Now the `pkg` directory is detected as a source root and my errors are gone.

Comment: This worked for me, although some of the locations of things are different on a Mac.