# python3: import another function in python file: No module named load

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

In the PyCharm editor, I have a python application named `project3` with the following directory structure. The file `load.py` just has a function (not class py file) `def read():`, `mip.py` is a py class file, and has own function method.

```
 Project
  |
  +---- project1
  |
  +---- project2
  |
  +---- project3
          |
          +---- cnn.py
          +---- load.py
          +---- mip.py
```

In the `cnn.py`, I want to import the `load` and `mip` file which I intend to use. My import code is as follows;

```
import load
from mip import f1
```

But I get the error:

```
No module named load
Unresolved reference 'mip'
```

Comment: mip or mlp? sense typo... also, add `__init__.py` in that folder.

Comment: Sorry, it is mip. how to add _init_.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pycharm you must add `project3` (and any other directories containing modules) as a root containing sources.

Right click on your `project3` directory and in the context menu select: **Mark Directory as** > **Sources Root**

Comment: Why pycharm need this setting?

Answer (score 1):

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746248/how-do-i-inform-pycharm-of-the-location-of-custom-modules) was answered, and since I don't have much experience with PyCharm, I'll avoid commenting on how you should go about it within the IDE.

Instead, I'll refer you in the direction of [the package docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__init__.py#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

The easiest solution is to just add a blank file named `__init__.py` in the same directory:

> In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package) variable, described later.

In the IDE, you may be able to do this by simply creating a new file in the project, naming it `__init__.py` and saving it, then restarting PyCharm.

If you'd like to do (or just read about) more complicated things with python modules and packages, you can see [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html#module-distutils).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and i added in  **init**.py file in directory and now its working fine.

1. Go to Directory from where file need to be import in other directory.
2. Create a new python new file with name **init**.py or copy from existing project and paste on same directory
3. Import same directory class or python file in other directory or same directory for different class or python file